# moshudp crosscompilation

Tags: cross-compilation, rust

I have a board with MIPS cpu of mips64el and buildRoot with toolchain. When I try compile a moshudp program by rust from buildRoot I get follow error

```
$ source $BUILD_ROOT_PATH/buildroot/output/host/environment_setup
$ cargo build --target mips64el-unknown-linux-gnuabi64
   Compiling syn v1.0.91
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`
```

I have mips64el-unknown-linux-gnuabi64 target installed only

```
$ rustup target list | grep install
  mips64el-unknown-linux-gnuabi64 (installed)
```

What's wrong?

**UPDATE**
Adding new target gave another error

```
$ rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
$ cargo build --target mips64el-unknown-linux-gnuabi64
= note: cc.br_real.br_real: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: The version is 22.04